# when will android webview js catch error?

Tags: javascript, android, logging, android-webview, bridge

I create a webview and some js binding in the app.
For safety reason I wrap js bridge function in try catch.
However, I have no idea what is caught by js catch function.
Because the errors happen randomly so I send out the error by GA but the event value is not set.

```js
    try {
      price = JsBridge.getProductPriceString('something wrogn');
    } catch (e) {
      ga('send', 'event', 'Error', 'Exception', e && e.toString());
      console.log("getPriceString", e);
      alert("get price string error:", e);
    }
```

I thought I can investigate from Android java side.
But I have no idea when will the Android js binding trigger js catch function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a debug like usually in Android

`Log.d("tag", "exception")`

if you use `alert` and `console.log` is not worked in Android directly